# Audio clicking/popping sound when audio starts (Macbook Pro 13" 2020)

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, click

I've bought a new Macbook Pro 13" 2020, which I got this Tuesday. I've had some issues with it making a clicking noise every time audio starts. It happens when I start a Youtube video, but I've also tested if it does the same with videos or wav/mp3's on the harddrive and it does. So it's not streaming related or browser.

It's only really noticeable on headphones, but I think it happens on the speakers as well. It's not the headphones, tested with others.

It's a very short, high freq sorta click. It's really annoying. I see other have had the issue with the older 16" 2018, but couldn't find much on this new 13" 2020. Anyone know what could be wrong?

I've tried all the SMC, PRAM, Safe Mode etc.

Comment: A Mac that new... call Apple Support!

Comment: Just to follow up if anyone has similar issues:



Just called apple. They told me to try different headphones. I use Sennheiser HD 25 and they make the click. Switched over to my beyerdynamic 990 PRO which has no click. So he said it seems to be driver issues with certain headphones and the audio port. Seems to work when you use a minijack to USB-C converter for the headphones.